# Aysnc webapi post return before finishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I am making a asp.net webapi call that posts some data to the server and will need to be processed. The client does not need to wait for the processing to finish. I would like to return something like this

```
HttpResponseMessage objReturn = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
```

//start a thread to do some work processing the data

//return while the data is being processed
  return objReturn;

Most of the example I find are about how to use async methods and wait for the processing to complete. I need the opposite.

thanks for you suggestions.

more code for those asking, the following code gives me a warning that the method lacks await and will run synchronously.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
  HttpResponseMessage objReturn = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok);

  //data processing logic
  //something longer running that the client doesnt need to wait for 
  //like converting a pdf to jpg or other I/O operations

  return objReturn;

}
```

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `return while the data is being processed return objReturn;` this would require `Async` please provide more code as to what you have tired and or trying .. one line code above does not express what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I have mainly tried looking for examples of how to do this, I have found lots of warnings about doing it wrong, but I have not done any async programming with asp.net webapi's before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you want a user to call an API, quickly receive a response, and have that trigger a longer running task.

In general, you do not use Web Api to run this longer task, instead yo use a service (i.e. Windows Service).

That service will sit there ... waiting for work ...

your Api will give it work! (Using a database, queues, files, etc.)

However, depending on how important this is, how much effort, and how much time ... you may not want to create a whole separate service. There are some "tools" that can help you.

[QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2)

http://hangfire.io/

^^ They will help you run long tasks in your Api directly! ^^

Answer (score 1):

The warning explains most of your problems. Just decorating a method with async does not mean that it runs asynchronous automatically. If you don't have any asynchronous work in your data processing logic it will run synchronously. Event if you have some asynchronous calls in there, the compiler can decide to run it synchronously if it think that's the better option. Remember that asynchronous work does [NOT involve another thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Some hints what you can do. First, you should make your I/O calls asynchronous. The .NET framework offers a lot you can use here. Second, you should not do that work in a controller. A controller should be small and don't do heavy processing, because it is your communicator to the rest of the world. Pass everything that needs more processing to a queue where a worker role (such as a Windows Service) picks up the work that needs to be done. With that the controller has nothing to do as passing data to the queue, give a result to the client that it was put into the queue ... and done. After that your controller can pick up additional work.